# R: add column with slope coefficient for values over time

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which has values over time.  The colnames reflect the time in milliseconds.  I would like to add an additional column with the slope coefficient of a line of best fit for each token.

`Token   0ms    20ms   40ms   60ms   80ms
 1       2.5    3.7    4.8    5.2    6.3
 2       3.6    4.9    5.2    6.1    7.8
 3       1.1    3.2    4.6    7.8    9.1
 4       4.5    3.3    2.1    1.9    NA
 5       2.1    3.5    3.7    NA     NA`

Some rows have NAs, as not all tokens are active for the same amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d  <- read.table(text=
"Token 0ms 20ms 40ms 60ms 80ms
1     2.5 3.7 4.8 5.2 6.3
2     3.6 4.9 5.2 6.1 7.8
3     1.1 3.2 4.6 7.8 9.1
4     4.5 3.3 2.1 1.9 NA
5     2.1 3.5 3.7 NA NA",
header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE)
slopes <- apply(as.matrix(d[,-1]),1,
         function(y) {
           fit <- lm(y~t,
              data=data.frame(y,
                       t=seq(0,length=length(y),by=20)))
           coef(fit)[2]
         })
data.frame(d,slopes,check.names=FALSE)
##   Token 0ms 20ms 40ms 60ms 80ms  slopes
## 1     1 2.5  3.7  4.8  5.2  6.3  0.0455
## 2     2 3.6  4.9  5.2  6.1  7.8  0.0480
## 3     3 1.1  3.2  4.6  7.8  9.1  0.1030
## 4     4 4.5  3.3  2.1  1.9   NA -0.0450
## 5     5 2.1  3.5  3.7   NA   NA  0.0400
```